# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i am trying to connect my java app with sql database and when i click on save button it gives me following error

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

here's my code

```
        name = full_name_input.getText();
        Fname = father_name_input.getText();
        cnic = father_cnic_input.getText();
        DOB = Integer.parseInt(DOB_input.getText());
        Class_V = Integer.parseInt(class_input.getText()); 
        prsnt_add = present_add_input.getText();
        city = city_input.getText();
        province = radio_text;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///UserDetails", "root", "sahanj");
            pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into UserDetails values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            pst.setString(1, name);
            pst.setString(2, Fname);
            pst.setString(3, cnic);`enter code here`
            pst.setInt(4, DOB);
            pst.setInt(5, Class_V);
            pst.setString(6, prsnt_add);
            pst.setString(7, city);
            pst.setString(8, province);

            int x = pst.executeUpdate();

            if (x>0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Saved !\n");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Not Saved !\n");
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
}
```

Comment: try using complete path `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/UserDetails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error generally occur because of following reason.
1.hostname in JDBC URL is not correct.
2.port number is not correct.
3.db server is not up.
for these take following step
1. give full JDBC url or test with ping.
2. check in my.cnf of mysql.
3. start the db.

Comment: actually i am new to java and doing my best to learn it so can you plzzz describe it in simplde words i want to make my laptop as a databse i have installed my SQL and well as jar file of connector